# Difference of principles behing CopyOnWriteArrayList and ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: arraylist, concurrenthashmap, copy-on-write

In the advanced java collections API, we have CopyOnWriteArrayList and ConcurrentHashMap. yet the underlying principles on these data structures are different. i.e ConcurrentHashMap only locks a segment of the Map on which the write operation is happening. This is how it prevents synchronization problems without affecting performance.

CopyOnWriteArrayList on the other hand prevents concurrency problems by making a duplicate of the original List. Why are these implementations so different? is Java just testing to see which one works better?

Answer (score 0):

A concurrent data structure is designed to ensure that any sequence of individual operations on the data structure will always leave it in a state which is consistent from its own point of view, but a "snapshot" formed by reading the data structure piece by piece may not necessarily represent any state which the data structure ever held.  For example, if while one is reading out an collection of users, "Zachary" is renamed to "Adam", the renamed user might get read out as "Adam", "Zachary", both, or neither.  Even if during the enumeration the collection was never in a state where the user never existed with both names, or didn't exist with either, the enumeration might make it look like it did.

A copy-on-write collection is designed to let one take a snapshot of the collection's entire state and guarantee that there was some moment in time when the collection actually had that state.  The result of every action, including snapshot requests, should be consistent with each action having been performed at some discrete moment in time time between when the request was issued and when it was reported to have completed.  If two requests are given before either completes, the selection of which action precedes the other is arbitrary, but there must be a globally-consistent ordering.